# Git Submodules equivalent for url.insteadof

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a couple Git repositories that all have one or more submodule referenced and both are corporate lan / internal https URLs (and thereby only accessible from the corp lan).

From the outside / public network, ssh access to the repositories IS however possible and I can mitigate switching the main repositories' URLs back and forth via a global .gitconfig url.insteadOf redirection, but that insteadOf rule doesn't seem to apply to the submodules (which also are https urls).

Is there any other way than to adapt each repository's .git/config file ... i.e something I can set in the global .gitconfig as well?

Comment: `insteadOf` configuration entries are ordinary Git configuration entries, and thus exist (at least potentially) in all config locations. So `git config --global ...` should do what you need (though you may need several rules depending on what is in each `.gitmodules` file). If it's not working, perhaps Git runs config with `--file` or `--blob`, which would be harder to work around. I have not actually tried this (I generally avoid submodules!).

Comment: @Jörg B. did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Carlos I did what torek suggested and have insteadOf statements in my (global) .gitconfig file.. and it works like a charm. Btw torek - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a way using git configuration and went with a brute force:

```
# test step, replace the "url = https://github.com/" manually
# verify the desired effect
# note the comma in sed command, it's unusual and valid
sed 's,https://github.com/,git@github.com:,g' .git/modules/*/config | grep url
# -i to modify the files
sed -i 's,https://github.com/,git@github.com:,g' .git/modules/*/config
```

from the parent repository.

or go with @torek's `--global` if affecting global config is not a problem:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
# or 
git config --global url."https://github".insteadOf git://github
# for reverse
```

Comment: And for submodules not yet checked-out you can do: `git -c url.git@github.com:.insteadOf=https://github.com/ submodule update --init --remote --recursive`

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon. This is great! Your comment worked for me! To be specific, I used `git -c url.https://github.com/.insteadOf=git@github.com: submodule update --init --recursive` to change the reference to submodules in public repos, without using an ssh key

Answer (score 2):

If you're not happy with changing your global configuration, then you probably need to configure each submodule separately, since each submodule is its own repository.

Fortunately git supplies [`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt) command, which

> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule.

What's important is that it really happens in each checked out submodule. *Meaning that before you run `git submodule update` some submodules will get ignored.*

So

```
$ git config --local url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
$ git submodule foreach --recursive \
    'git config --local url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"'
```

should do the trick for the main repository, its submodules and submodules of their submodules.