# Change multiple submodules sheme from git to https when cloning in dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, github, dockerfile, git-submodules

I have a repo to clone and it has multiple submodules in it. This can be shown by running,
`git config --file=.gitmodules -l` Which results to

```
submodule.third-party/lua-resty-lrucache.path=third-party/lua-resty-lrucache
submodule.third-party/lua-resty-lrucache.url=git@github.com:openresty/lua-resty-lrucache.git
submodule.third-party/oxd-web-lua.path=third-party/oxd-web-lua
submodule.third-party/oxd-web-lua.url=git@github.com:GluuFederation/oxd-web-lua.git
submodule.third-party/json-logic-lua.path=third-party/json-logic-lua
submodule.third-party/json-logic-lua.url=https://git.rucciva.one/rucciva/json-logic-lua.git
submodule.third-party/lua-resty-jwt.path=third-party/lua-resty-jwt
submodule.third-party/lua-resty-jwt.url=git@github.com:altexy/lua-resty-jwt.git
submodule.third-party/lua-resty-hmac.path=third-party/lua-resty-hmac
submodule.third-party/lua-resty-hmac.url=git@github.com:jkeys089/lua-resty-hmac.git
submodule.third-party/nginx-lua-prometheus.path=third-party/nginx-lua-prometheus
submodule.third-party/nginx-lua-prometheus.url=git@github.com:knyar/nginx-lua-prometheus.git
submodule.third-party/lua-resty-session.path=third-party/lua-resty-session
submodule.third-party/lua-resty-session.url=git@github.com:bungle/lua-resty-session.git
```

I don't want to use ssh when doing a clone since I want to enable dockerhub autobuild. I just want to convert all `git@github.com` scheme to `https://...`

I have tried using `git config --file=.gitmodules submodules.Submod.url https://github.com/jkeys089/lua-resty-hmac.git` but I am not sure how to convert all the submodules leave alone one submodule.

How can I convert all the submodules' scheme from `git`to `https`. in dockerfile

Comment: `git config --global url.https://github.com.insteadOf git@github.com:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing https-address of submodules in .git/config to ssh-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241341/changing-https-address-of-submodules-in-git-config-to-ssh-address)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44788335/7976758

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I went on a different route. I override .gitmodules file during image build.