# Inconsistent git submodule remote url

Tags: git, url, ssh, git-submodules, git-remote

I have a git submodule:

```sh
$ cd zathura
$ git remote get-url origin
ssh://git@github.com/pwmt/zathura.git
$ cd ..
```

But inside `.git/config`

```sh
[submodule "zathura"]
    url = https://github.com/pwmt/zathura.git
```

And inside `.gitmodules`

```
[submodule "zathura"]
    path = zathura
    url = https://github.com/pwmt/zathura.git
    ignore = dirty
```

---

#### Questions

Why the Remote urls are inconsistent (a mixture of https and ssh)?
Is this  valid? Or is it due to some mistake that I might have done? How can I have consistent remote url and which url is used by git?

Comment: Did you have an `insteadOf` in place when you did the submodule init? (I'm not sure if this does any rewrites of the in-`.git/config` entry or not.) How did you initialize the submodule originally? In any case there's nothing fundamentally wrong here: the `.gitmodules` line is merely an instruction for `git submodule init` in case there's nothing more detailed; the `.git/config` entry is set up *by* `git submodule init`; and the remote's URL is the one actually used, configured by the initial `git clone` and adjustable any time after that.

Comment: I initialized using `git submodule add --force --name "${RepositoryName}" "${Url}" "${RepositoryPath}"`. Yes, I have used `insteadOf`. So, when using `insteadOf` the Url is not reflected in `.gitmodules` and `.git/config`?

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure if `insteadOf` causes a rewrite at instantiation time. You could easily test this though.

Answer (score 0):

From the [comments of Git Submodules equivalent for `url.insteadof`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51920532/6309), this should work:

```
git -c url.https://github.com/.insteadOf=git@github.com: submodule update --init --recursive
```

That way, you can test the effect of an `insteadOf` directive, and make sure HTTPS is used everywhere.