# Git submodule update submodule to all branches

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

I have a parent repository ***A*** with project ***B*** as a submodule. Recently, the URL for project ***B*** has changed, and I want to update that information in repository ***A*** for all commits and for all branches under repository ***A***.

I know that `submodule set-url path new-url` will update the ".gitmodules" file and the ".git/config" folder but I am not sure how to update all the commits and all the branches.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can never change any existing commit at all.

If you want to *rewrite* repository ***A***, to create a new repository ***APrime***, in which all the commits have a different URL for repository ***B***, you can do this with `git filter-branch` (deprecated) or `git filter-repo`.  There is no recipe for this so you will have to write a little bit of code.

In general, the correct way to handle this is *not to do this*.  Just make new commits in ***A*** that record the new URL and use Git's "insteadOf" feature.  See, e.g., [Git Submodules equivalent for url.insteadof](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44788335/1256452).